# how to update constraints in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout

Hi i am new for ios and in my app i have added one AutoGrowingTextview and

i have added constraints to this textview
1)top space
2)leading space 
3)trailing space
4)height

and i have added button on my main view and when i click that button i want to set  textview height is "zero"

for this i have written below code but it's not working please help me

### my code:-

```
AutoGrowingTextView:-
---------------------
.h file:-
---------

    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

    @interface AUIAutoGrowingTextView : UITextView

    @property (nonatomic) CGFloat maxHeight;
    @property (nonatomic) CGFloat minHeight;

    // TODO:
    //@property(nonatomic) UIControlContentVerticalAlignment verticalAlignment;

    @end

.m file:-
---------
#import "AUIAutoGrowingTextView.h"

@interface AUIAutoGrowingTextView()

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSLayoutConstraint *heightConstraint;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSLayoutConstraint *maxHeightConstraint;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSLayoutConstraint *minHeightConstraint;

@end

@implementation AUIAutoGrowingTextView

-(id) initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        [self commonInit];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void) awakeFromNib
{
    [self commonInit];    
}

-(void) commonInit
{
    // If we are using auto layouts, than get a handler to the height constraint.
    for (NSLayoutConstraint *constraint in self.constraints) {
        if (constraint.firstAttribute == NSLayoutAttributeHeight) {
            self.heightConstraint = constraint;
            break;
        }
    }    
    if (!self.heightConstraint) {
        // TODO: We might use auto layouts but set the height of the textView by using a top + bottom constraints. In this case we would want to manually create a height constraint    
    }
}

- (void) layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];

    if (self.heightConstraint) {
        [self handleLayoutWithAutoLayouts];
    }
    else {
        [self handleLayoutWithoutAutoLayouts];
    }

    // Center vertically
    // We're  supposed to have a maximum height contstarint in code for the text view which will makes the intrinsicSide eventually higher then the height of the text view - if we had enough text.
    // This code only center vertically the text view while the context size is smaller/equal to the text view frame.
    if (self.intrinsicContentSize.height <= self.bounds.size.height) {
        CGFloat topCorrect = (self.bounds.size.height - self.contentSize.height * [self zoomScale])/2.0;
        topCorrect = ( topCorrect < 0.0 ? 0.0 : topCorrect );
        self.contentOffset = (CGPoint){.x = 0, .y = -topCorrect};
    }
}

-(void) handleLayoutWithAutoLayouts
{
    CGSize intrinsicSize = self.intrinsicContentSize;
    if (self.minHeight) {
        intrinsicSize.height = MAX(intrinsicSize.height, self.minHeight);
    }
    if (self.maxHeight) {
        intrinsicSize.height = MIN(intrinsicSize.height, self.maxHeight);
    }
    self.heightConstraint.constant = intrinsicSize.height;
}

-(void) handleLayoutWithoutAutoLayouts
{
    // TODO:
}

- (CGSize)intrinsicContentSize
{
    CGSize intrinsicContentSize = self.contentSize;

    if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 7.0) {
        intrinsicContentSize.width += (self.textContainerInset.left + self.textContainerInset.right ) / 2.0f;
        intrinsicContentSize.height += (self.textContainerInset.top + self.textContainerInset.bottom) / 2.0f;
    }

    return intrinsicContentSize;
}


@end

mainClass:-
----------
    #import "ViewController.h"
#import "AUIAutoGrowingTextView.h"

   @interface ViewController ()

   @property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet AutoGrowingTextView*growingTextView;

   @end
    @implementation ViewController
    @synthesize textViewheight;

    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        //self.growingTextView.maxHeight = 800;
        self.growingTextView.text = @"Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.Dispose of any resources that can be recreated. Dispose of any resources that can be recreated. Dispose";
     }

    - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
    {
        [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    - (IBAction)buttonTapped:(id)sender {
        textViewheight.constant = 0;
        [self.view setNeedsLayout];
    }
    @end
```

Comment: There is no issue with the code. Can you make sure you have connected IBAction and IBOutlets properly?

Comment: sorry i am using AutoGrowing Textview i have updated my code please see once and help me where is mistack

Answer (score 0):

When you change height constraint and call `[self.view setNeedsLayout]` `layoutSubviews` will be called. Inside `layoutSubviews` again you are trying to change height of the textView. Before proceeding further you can check for below condition in `layoutSubviews`

```
if (self.heightConstraint.constant == 0) {
    return;
}
```

Comment: yes i kept [self.view setNeedsLayout] in my button action but it's not working